# How to use hooks in CS-Cart for overriding footer.tpl file

Tags: cs-cart

I am new to cs-cart and 
I am trying to use hooks in cs-cart. 
I had gone through some cs-cart website  but not getting proper answer.
 Suppose if i want to override footer.tpl file with new content then how can i do it using hooks.
 Just tell me the steps what code to write in index.tpl file and where to keep new footer.tpl file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you to check this brief guide: http://docs.cs-cart.com/hooks.

Assuming you're on a version 4.x.x:

- You don't need to edit anything in index.tpl, just take note of the name of the hook you want to use (I suppose you want to use this one {hook name="index:footer"})
- Write your new template and give it the name footer.[override/pre/post].tpl
- Save this new .tpl file in themes/[your_theme_name]/templates/addons/my_changes/hooks/index (maybe you need to create such directories in your folders tree)
- Make sure you have the "my changes" addon installed and active. You can check it through your admin area of the store.

And that's it, it should work.

Notes:

- I've seen no standard "footer.tpl" file in version 4.x.x., so the above instructions work, but they only append content at the end of the page. Customization of such page area can be done via the layout and theme editor on the admin area of the store.
- The naming algorithm mentioned on the documentation of cs-cart is for
  version 3.x.x. Since version 4.x.x. the folders names have varied.
  You should replace `skins/[skin name]/[admin|customer]` for
  `design/themes/[your_theme_name]/templates`